# Plain text zoom

Tags: windows-store-apps

Is it possible to zoom in and out of plain text? I'm developing an app now and would like my users to be able to pinch the text so it is magnified, just like when viewing a web page in IE. I tried setting the CSS property -ms-content-zooming to zoom but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this with some text and the below works fine.

Taken from Jeremy's awesome CodeShow application from http://codeshow.codeplex.com

```
<div id="container">
    Your Text Here
    <img src="oceanrocks.jpg" />
</div>
```

```
.zoom #container {
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:scroll;
    -ms-content-zooming:zoom;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-max:1000%;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-min:20%;
}

.zoom #container img {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I added the overflow property in addition to the -ms-content-zooming property in order to get this to work. I have the codeSHOW app installed on my surface but most of their samples don't support optical zoom including the "Text Properties" section. Which sample in the codeSHOW demonstrates this?